# Error homestead up

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm installing homestead for **Laravel 5** (Windows)

I've Already installed **Vagrant** and **VirtualBox**

Following this tutorial: https://laracasts.com/lessons/say-hello-to-laravel-homestead-two

When i run
    homestead up

This is the error result:

```
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>
): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 3 column 1 (P
sych::SyntaxError)
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse
_stream'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:153:in `parse
'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:129:in `load'

from C:/Users/Mark/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/laravel/homestead/Vag
rantfile:18:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/c
onfig/v2/loader.rb:37:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/c
onfig/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/c
onfig/loader.rb:103:in `block (2 levels) in load'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/c
onfig/loader.rb:97:in `each'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/c
onfig/loader.rb:97:in `block in load'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/c
onfig/loader.rb:94:in `each'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/c
onfig/loader.rb:94:in `load'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/v
agrantfile.rb:28:in `initialize'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/e
nvironment.rb:691:in `new'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/e
nvironment.rb:691:in `vagrantfile'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/e
nvironment.rb:441:in `host'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/e
nvironment.rb:207:in `block in action_runner'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/a
ction/runner.rb:33:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/a
ction/runner.rb:33:in `run'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/e
nvironment.rb:428:in `hook'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/e
nvironment.rb:673:in `unload'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/bin/vagrant:1
77:in `ensure in <main>'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/bin/vagrant:1
77:in `<main>'
```

This is my YAML file:

```
---

ip: "192.168.10.10"

memory: 2048
cpus: 1


provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub



keys:

    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:

    - map: ~/Projects

      to: /home/vagrant/Projects



sites:

    - map: myawesomeproject.app

      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/Laravel/public



databases:

    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local#
 blackfire:#
     - id: foo#
       token: bar#
       client-id: foo#
       client-token: bar#
 ports:#
     - send: 93000#
       to: 9300#
     - send: 7777#
       to: 777#
       protocol: udp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because the # not in correct way.

it should be like

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects

sites:
    - map: myawesomeproject.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/Laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 93000
#       to: 9300
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Comment: Thank you, I just figured that out. I've also tried to delete all of the lines with "#" in them.